# Tic Tac Toe: display score, prevent duplicate entries, print draw

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and programming, and I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game based on specific guidelines.

This is my code:

```
import random
import time

marker = {'Player 1 ': 'X', 'Player 2 ': 'O', }
board = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
turn = '0'
game_round ='0'

def display_board(board):
    print('7  |8  |9')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('4  |5  |6')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('1  |2  |3')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')


def choose_first():
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'Player 1 '
    elif random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        return 'Player 2 '

def display_score(score):
    score = 0
    if score(board,mark):
        score += 1 

     #Prints final score after each round

def place_marker(board, marker, position):

    board[position] = marker

    #places marker (X or O) in position 


def win_check(board,mark):
    win_combs = (
    [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
    [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7],)
    for comb in win_combs:
        if (board[comb[0]] == board[comb[1]] == board[comb[2]] == mark):
            return True
    return False

    #returns True if 3 same marks (X or O) are in line(win)
def board_check(board):
    if board != [' '] :
        return False
    else:
        return True 

    #returns False if there are still empty blocks in the board
    #or True otherwise.
def player_choice(board, turn):
    first = turn
    while turn not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split():
          turn = input(turn +'Insert number 1-9 :')
    return int(turn)

    #Player (turn) selects a block
    #An int is returned [1,9]
    #Checks if value is already submitted in the same block
def replay(): 
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

    #Asks players to play again
def next_player(turn): 
    first=turn
    if first == 'Player 1 ':
        return 'Player 2 '
    else:
        return 'Player 1 '

def main():
    score = {} # dictionary containing players scores
    print('Getting ready to start!\nCoin Toss ', end = '')
    for t in range(10):
        print(".", flush='True', end=' ')
        time.sleep(0.2)
    print()
    # turn variable reffers to the player whos currently playing
    turn = choose_first() 
    print("\n " + turn + ' goes first!!')
    # first variable reffers to the player who played first
    first = turn 
    game_round = 1
    while True:

        theBoard = [' '] * 10 

        game_on = True
        while game_on:
            display_board(theBoard)
            position = player_choice(theBoard, turn) 
            place_marker(theBoard, marker[turn], position) 
            if win_check(theBoard, marker[turn]):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print(turn+ "Won")
                score[turn] = score.get(turn, 0) + 1
                game_on = False
            elif board_check(theBoard): 
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Draw')
                game_on = False
            else: 
                turn = next_player(turn)
        if not replay():
            ending = ''
            if game_round>1 : ending = 's'
            print("After {} round{}".format(game_round, ending))
            display_score(score)
            break
        else :
            game_round += 1
            #in the next round the other player plays first
            turn = next_player(first) 
            first = turn
main()
```

Issues:

1. The **def board_check** is not working properly and when the board is full the program still accepts submissions.
2. I want to prevent user from submitting a value in a block that's already occupied by another value within the **def player_choice**.
3. I can't get the **def display_score** to work.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be far from complete, but as you are trying to learn it should at least allow you to start thinking about some next steps.

1.
I don't think you need to define "board" as a global list. If you want your functions to accept a board state then passing them "theBoard" as you do in main() should be sufficient.

Also the reason that the program still accepts submissions is that you are not performing any kind of check to see if a space is already occupied.

```
def place_marker(board, marker, position):

    board[position] = marker

    #places marker (X or O) in position
```

Should be something like:

```
def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    if board[position] == ' ':
        board[position] = marker
    else:
        print("That space is already occupied.")
```

Then you need to think about what you want the program to do when someone tries to put a piece on top of another piece.

If board check is supposed to check if the board is full (and thus the game is over but no one has won) then one way to achieve this is to loop over the spaces checking if they are equal to ' ', if they all are then the board is full. However a quicker way to do this is with:

```
def board_full(board):
    if ' ' not in board:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

2.
I think you are referring to what I suggested for your place_marker function?

3.
Display score: Okay, here your mistake is that your function takes only score as an argument but then uses board. Board is globally defined as an empty board (well actually it is full of spaces, this is also unecessary you can just use empty quotes).

This function is also changing the value of the score but really what I think you want to do is change the value of the score when you perform your win_check. If Player 1 wins then add 1 to player 1's score.

Finally display_score doesn't display anything because there is no print function. print(score) is probably what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Charmader35!Its been a great help..I changed the code in ** def place_marker** and it works but when the player submits a value on an occupied spot misses his turn.I forgot print(score) to print before..but im still having trouble adding win points on each player..

Comment: Could i avoid the missing turn by checking for occupied spots inside the 'def player_choice(board, turn)' ?

Comment: You could have place_marker return True or False, and don't switch to the next player until it returns True.

Answer (score 1):

The `theBoard` board is just too long: your grid is supposed to be 3x3, but it has ten cells...

More precisely, you assign markers to the cells by accessing the cells with their indices, which is comprised between `1` and `9`. However, Python's lists are indexed from `0`, so the first cell at index `0` is never assigned.

The problem with your `board_check` function is that it tests if `board` is equal to `[' ']`, while you want to check if `board` still contains a `' '`. Therefore, your function should be:

```
def board_check(board):
    if ' ' not in board:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

But Pythons supports boolean, so this should be:

```
def board_check(board):
    return ' '  not in board
```

Going back to the `theBoard` board, now that `board_check` is alright. You need to change `theBoard = [' '] * 10` into `theBoard = [' '] * 9`. Then, when accessing the cells, you must pass the index minus `1`, because the elements will be shifted by one to the left.

The easiest fix, because of dependancies at other places of your code, is to pass `theBoard[1:]` instead of `theBoard` to `board_check`. This means "the sublist of `theBoard` that goes from 1 to the end".

---

Additionally, your `choose_first` function is wrong, and has a chance of returning `None`, ending in an exception. Your function is defined as follows:

```
def choose_first():
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'Player 1 '
    elif random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        return 'Player 2 '
```

Semantically, your code means:

> Toss a coin. If it's head, Player 1 begins. If it's tails, you toss another coin. If that second coin is tails, Player 2 begins.

What if the first `randint` gives you `1`, and the second gives you `0`? Nobody begins.

You need to produce a single random number (toss a single coin), and make your decision according to this value:

```
def choose_first():
    value = random.randint(0, 1)
    if value == 0:
        return 'Player 1 '
    else:
        return Player 2 '
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Right leg for your time. I could never think of my 'def choose_first()' issue, its been a great help.Great explenation and you cleared a lot of things for me. I used 10 cells instead of 9 to make it easier for the user (submitting values 1-9 instead of 0-8).

Comment: @Mike_R In such situations, a good solution is to code the core functions (make a board, put a marker in a cell...), and write functions that act as an interface between the core and the controller (ie, the main function/loop/script). For instance, you could define a `convert_index` function that takes an integer between 1 and 9, and takes it back between 0 and 8. This way, the main code is natural (it makes sense from a human point of view), but the right data is provided to the core. The best way (IMO, especially in Python) is to encapsulate the core in a class, which here would be `Board`.